# How to use files copied in Windows File Explorer on the command line?

Tags: windows-explorer, command-line-arguments

In Windows File Explorer, you can highlight several files and then click the "Copy path" button from the menu. Show below is an example. I'd then like to process these files on the command line, preferably in a PowerShell terminal. I've tried enclosing them in more quotes, single quotes, and backticks, to no avail. Here's an example of the files copied to the clipboard:

"C:\Users\me\100_0909.jpg" "C:\Users\me\100_0521.jpg" "C:\Users\me\100_0519.jpg"

I'd like to be able to take the files above and include them in a command like:

magick "C:\Users\me\100_0909.jpg" "C:\Users\me\100_0521.jpg" "C:\Users\me\100_0519.jpg" +append new.jpg

command-line powershell